# Using Lambdas and Generics

Tags: java, java-8

I am learning Java 8 and I am trying to use lambdas and generics together and I wrote this small example

```
import java.util.function.*;

public class LambdaTest<T> {

    public T calculate(T x, T y, BiFunction<T, T, T> func) {
        return func.apply(x, y);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LambdaTest<Integer> l = new LambdaTest<Integer>();
        System.out.println("" + l.calculate(10, 10, (x, y) -> x + y));
        System.out.println("" + l.calculate(10, 10, (x, y) -> x * y));
        System.out.println("" + l.calculate(10, 10, (x, y) -> x / y));
        System.out.println("" + l.calculate(10, 10, (x, y) -> x - y));
        LambdaTest<Double> l2 = new LambdaTest<Double>();
        System.out.println("" + l2.calculate(10.0, 10.0, (x, y) -> x + y));
    }
}
```

Few questions I have are

1. My lambdas are being defined twice `(x, y) -> x + y`. is it possible to define these only once.
2. It seems that everytime this code is run, it will box 10 to Integer and then run the code. is it possible that I can define this for `int` rather than `Integer`. I tried doing `new LambdaTest<int>` but it did not work.

Comment: 2. No, generics don't work with primitive types. You can define a `IntLambdaTest` that is unrelated to the generic `LambdaTest`, but uses `int` for its first two parameters, and a `IntBinaryOperator` for its last.

Comment: A nice fact is that you can use a method reference for summation: `IntBinaryOperator a = Integer::sum;`. You can use the same method for a `BinaryOperator<Integer>` and a `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No. One is of type `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>`, whereas the other is of type `BiFunction<Double, Double, Double>`. They're thus not compatible with each other.
2. To avoid the unboxing and the boxing, you would have to use DoubleBinaryOperator and IntBinaryOperator, which use primitive types. But then you would need two different interfaces.

Answer (score 5):

1. No it is not possible because the lambda are actually different. In the first one, both `x` and `y` are of type `Integer`, whereas in the second one, both `x` and `y` are of type `Double`. Unfortunately, `Integer` and `Double` are both [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) and the `+` operation is not defined for general `Number`.
2. It is also not possible to use a primitive type with generics. However, you could use [`IntBinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html): this is a functional interface operating on two `int` values and returning an `int` value.

Answer (score 2):

For summing you can use a reference to the corresponding method:

```
System.out.println("" + l.calculate(10, 10, Integer::sum));
System.out.println("" + l2.calculate(10.0, 10.0, Double::sum));
```

Here you can see that it's actually not the same code, just similar.

As for boxing, for float/double types the JIT compiler can inline your lambda, see that boxed value does not escape and eliminate the boxing. For example, let's consider such method:

```
public static void testCalculate(double a, double b) {
    LambdaTest<Double> l = new LambdaTest<Double>();
    double d = l.calculate(a, b, (x, y) -> x + y);
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

The x64 assembler starts like this:

```
# {method} {0x0000000051710670} 'testCalculate' '(DD)V' in 'LambdaTest'
# parm0:    xmm0:xmm0   = double
# parm1:    xmm1:xmm1   = double
#           [sp+0xa0]  (sp of caller)
mov %eax,-0x6000(%rsp)
push %rbp
sub $0x90,%rsp  ;*synchronization entry
                ; - LambdaTest::testCalculate@-1 (line 10)
vaddsd %xmm1,%xmm0,%xmm2  ;*dadd
                          ; - LambdaTest::lambda$testCalculate$0@8 (line 11)
                          ; - LambdaTest$$Lambda$1/1555845260::apply@8
                          ; - LambdaTest::calculate@3 (line 6)
                          ; - LambdaTest::testCalculate@24 (line 11)
movabs $0x8c900c78,%r10  ;   {oop(a 'java/lang/Class' = 'java/lang/System')}
mov 0x6c(%r10),%r10d
mov (%r10),%rax  ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x0000000005bd3426
mov %rax,%r11
and $0x7,%r11
mov %r10,%r9  ;*getstatic out
              ; - LambdaTest::testCalculate@35 (line 12)
... the rest is inlined code from PrintStream.println(double);
```

So as you can see, the whole lambda call and boxing is unwinded and simplified to single `vaddsd` instruction. No calls, no boxing, no memory access, just two xmm registers. Really fast.

Unfortunately for `Integer/Long` the resulting assembler is much less clean due to caching of some values. The JIT compiler cannot just replace this with simple `add`, because it's not known exactly that, for example, for cached `Integer.valueOf(10)` you will actually get the primitive `10` value. Who knows, probably you replaced some values using the reflection to make `2+2=5`, for example. Nevertheless new objects are not created: if the arguments absent in cache, then `new Integer` is actually not called.

Comment: I don’t think that the specification mandates that the JIT/optimizer has to maintain compatibility with Reflection-access override-patched canonical `Integer` instances, esp. not for `Long`, where caching is not mandatory. Nevertheless, this proves my long standing opinion that making caching of some values mandatory was a big mistake.

Comment: @Holger, yesterday's solutions are today's problems. I guess HotSpot optimization engineers blame this caching every single day. Nevertheless I agree. I see no reason why certain pattern of bytecode in `Integer.valueOf` could not be detected by JIT-compiler and optimized out... Probably it has some unforeseen consequences I don't aware of.

Comment: Well, I noticed the potential problems right when the specification was released and din’t understood, why the made it *mandatory* rather than just recommended. Writing programs that rely on the identity of boxed values is still discouraged anyway. But I don’t think that the JIT compiler has to analyze the byte code of `Integer.valueOf` as it already knows its semantics. There are other methods which get intrinsified without ever looking at their actual byte code (e.g. the methods in `java.lang.Math`)…

Comment: @Holger, seems that current JDK9 codebase does not intrinsify the `Integer.valueOf`. OTOH, it's already [marked](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/file/4be07e0eb9b6/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l977) as `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate`. Probably we'll see some improvements here...

Answer (score 1):

> 1. My lambdas are being defined twice (x, y) -> x + y. is it possible to define these only once.

You cannot avoid repeating `(x, y) -> x + y` however **you can avoid creating two LambdaTest instances**.

Actually you don't need any LambdaTest instance when using a **static generic function** instead of a generic class. Here the code:

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class LambdaTest2 {

    public static <T> T calculate(T x, T y, BiFunction<T, T, T> func) {
        return func.apply(x, y);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("" + calculate(10, 10, (x, y) -> x + y));
        System.out.println("" + calculate(10, 10, (x, y) -> x * y));
        System.out.println("" + calculate(10, 10, (x, y) -> x / y));
        System.out.println("" + calculate(10, 10, (x, y) -> x - y));
        System.out.println("" + calculate(10.0, 10.0, (x, y) -> x + y));
    }
}
```

---

> 2. It seems that everytime this code is run, it will box 10 to Integer and then run the code. is it possible that I can define this for int rather than Integer. I tried doing new LambdaTest but it did not work.

As already explained by jb-nizet:

> To avoid the unboxing and the boxing, you would have to use DoubleBinaryOperator and IntBinaryOperator, which use primitive types. But then you would need two different interfaces.